# How can I create this complicated layout using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, layout, vertical-alignment

### OVERVIEW

I've read a bunch of the "vertical-centering with CSS" tutorials out there:

- http://emergentweb.com/test/valign.html
- http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/
- http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html
- http://www.alistapart.com/d/footers/footer_variation1.html
- http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html

... but there is another component to my layout that is not represented in any of these methods in addition to the vertical centering.

[image: layout].

There are 2 components to this layout. First, vertically & horizontally centering the content between the header and footer (which is a [sticky footer](http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/)). I have the code in a fiddle to demonstrate but I haven't been able to get this to work in IE (the code is at the bottom of the post).

- http://jsfiddle.net/UnsungHero97/yZPwu/4/embedded/result/

The second component is where the green arrow is pointing. That represents a hidden element which is meant to expand vertically downwards when clicking on some of the text. However, **I DO NOT WANT** this expansion to move the content upward as if everything was being centered... I want this element to expand downwards **without** affecting the position of the content **AND** pushing the sticky footer down as it expands. In most cases, a browser scrollbar will appear.

***So the effect of the hidden element expanding should be like a banner falling off an edge.***

This is what the layout should look like **after** the hidden element has been expanded:

[image: layout2]

---

### QUESTION

So how would I achieve this layout using **only** CSS and have it be cross-browser compatible Please let me know if I need to explain further to clarify confusion.

---

### CODE SO FAR

Note... I have left out some of the boilerplate code that comes with [HTML5 BoilerPlate](http://html5boilerplate.com/).

CSS

```
/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   General Layout
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
html,body {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    color: #696969;
}

#wrapper {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 936px;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Header
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
header {
    background-color: #232323;
    height: 108px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 24px 0px 8px 0px;
    position: relative;
}

#header-content {
    height: 100%;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    position: relative;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   Footer
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
footer {
    background-color: #dbdbdb;
    border-top: 1px solid #bababa;
    height: 30px;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 936px;
    margin-top: -32px;
    position: relative;
}

#footer-content {
    border-top: 1px solid #f8f8f8;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    position: relative;
}

#footer-content > div {
    width: 800px;
    margin: 0px auto;
}


/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   DOWNLOADZONE
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#dl-info {
    width: 400px;
    margin: auto;
    display: table-cell !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#show-hide {
    margin: 8px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

/* --------------------------------------------------------------------------
   General helper classes
   -------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
.zone {
    background: none;
    border: 0px none;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 140px;
    padding-bottom: 31px;
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.border {
    border: 1px solid #454545;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}


/* Hide from both screenreaders and browsers: h5bp.com/u */
.hidden { 
    display: none !important;
    visibility: hidden;
}

/* Hide only visually, but have it available for screenreaders: h5bp.com/v */
.visuallyhidden { 
    border: 0;
    clip: rect(0 0 0 0);
    height: 1px;
    margin: -1px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 1px;
}

/* Extends the .visuallyhidden class to allow the element to be focusable when navigated to via the keyboard: h5bp.com/p */
.visuallyhidden.focusable:active, 
.visuallyhidden.focusable:focus { 
    clip: auto;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0;
    overflow: visible;
    position: static;
    width: auto;
}

/* Hide visually and from screenreaders, but maintain layout */
.invisible { visibility: hidden; }

/* Contain floats: h5bp.com/q */
.clearfix:before, 
.clearfix:after { 
    content: "";
    display: table;
}

.clearfix:after { clear: both; }

.clearfix { *zoom: 1; }
```

​
HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<!-- paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/ -->
<!-- misteroneill.com/improved-internet-explorer-targeting-through-body-classes/ -->
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie6 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie ie7 lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]> <html class="no-js ie ie8 lt-ie9 lt-ie8" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 9]> <html class="no-js ie ie9 lt-ie9" lang="en"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if (gte IE 9)|!(IE)]>
<!-->
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
    <title>Layout</title>
</head>

<body class="select-none">

    <div id="wrapper">

        <header>
            <div id="header-content">
            </div><!-- end #header-content -->
        </header><!-- end header -->

        <div id="downloadzone" class="zone clearfix">

            <div id="dl-info">
                <div class="border">
                    <div id="dl-button">Icon Here</div>
                    <div id="dl-extras">
                        <div id="dl-filename">text text text</div>
                        <div id="show-hide">CLICK TO SHOW/HIDE HIDDEN ELEMENT</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div><!-- end #downloadzone -->

    </div><!-- end #wrapper -->

    <footer>
        <div id="footer-content">
            <div class="border-highlight">
            </div><!-- end .border-highlight -->
        </div><!-- end #footer-content -->
    </footer><!-- end footer -->

</body>
</html>
​
```

Comment: +1, interesting question! A few questions: what browsers are you looking to support (I'm not sure how IE7 and lower handle table-cell for divs)? Is [this jsfiddle fork](http://jsfiddle.net/mxY2R/1/) sortoff the show/hide toggle you're looking to style?

Comment: uh,, what was wrong about `position: fixed` that you didn't use it?

Comment: @deathApril... haven't tried that yet but I don't think it'll work. try whipping up a demo and let me know if it works?

Comment: @Jeroen... that's exactly the opposite effect I'm looking for :) in your demo, the expansion slides the content up and treats everything as if it was centered. I'm looking for only the content to be centered and the hidden element to sort of "fall down" when it expands. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Hristo i saw the "sticky footer" page and it is placed at the end of page, not at the bottom of a browser window, so "position: fixed" won't work for you :(

Comment: @Jeroen... also, if you have a lot more content in that expanding element, the footer **is not** being pushed down.

Comment: @deathApril... yes! that's exactly right.

Comment: the "Text text text" element on your second image is not vertically centered between header and footer => it is not possible to achieve this design for "unknown height" (i.e. arbitrary top margin) without javascript (or totally messing up the HTML)

Comment: @deathApril... yes, I know it is not centered. What is important is that it used to be centered before the hidden element expanded. I want it to stay in the same place as the hidden element expands.

Comment: @Hristo you want to change the value for "margin-top" from "auto" to "what was caluclated as auto when this element was not visible" - i don't think this rule made it into current CSS implementations..

Comment: @Hristo yeah I understand, I was mainly trying to figure out the toggle-effect you're after. In other words, if in the mentioned jsfiddle the "pushing up" of main content is prevented (it stays v-centered) and the footer is pushed down as needed, then your problem is solved, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly (my apologies if I'm answering the wrong question here), you want an element of unknown height to be horizontally and vertically centered, with a possible other element beneath it that shouldn't affect the position when it's displayed?

How about using overflow? [Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/minitech/EZ5g2/) I'll put the code here soon.

Compatibility warning: the vertical centering method used will not work in Internet Explorer 7 or lower.

Comment: From the demo you have, it seems like that is what I want! Not that I particularly care about IE 7 or lower, but it would be nice to support those as well. 1. why does your solution not work for <= IE7 2. what would you recommend I do to support those?

Comment: absolute elements won't affect position of sibling elements, how exactly do you want to push footer down the page when the hidden content is shown and is too big??

Comment: @deathApril: I guess that's the part of the question that I didn't understand.

Comment: @minitech... the footer is important! it **must** be a sticky footer so it must be pushed down when the element expands (if there is enough content in the element, of course)

Comment: @Hristo: Ah, I understand now. Just give `#showme` 32 pixels of `padding-bottom`.

Comment: @minitech... cool. so would you mind adding in the header and footer from my fiddle above and updating your answer?

Comment: @minitech what does `padding-bottom` of an absolute element have to do with moving other elements around?

Comment: @deathApril: The footer is sticky. The extra padding, although not affecting other elements on the page, will affect the viewport and force it to scroll, making room for the sticky footer. (It's a good thing it's a footer!)

Comment: @minitech uh,, the sticky footer will stick to the original position, unaffected by the now scrollable viewport - but i will give you some time now, you might discover a miracle or something ;)

Comment: @Hristo: Oops. Scratch that. It's not possible without at least knowing either the height of the element or the height of its contents. (Or JavaScript.)

Comment: @minitech... without knowing the height of which element? hidden or the visible/centered content box?

Comment: @Hristo: Either or them would do.

Comment: @minitech... the visible/centered content box can have a fixed height and width; say height = 100px, width = 400px?

Comment: @Hristo: Oh, in that case, it's possible once again. I have to go now though, but I'll answer in a few hours! Sorry :(

Comment: @Hristo: I've been trying, but the sticky footer actually seems to make it impossible. Is approximating the centering okay? If you just go for a common screen size and use media queries for mobile devices and such, it should be fine just using a big value for `margin-top`, and doing the rest without fancy positioning.

Comment: @minitech... at this point it seems like getting exactly what I want without JavaScript is impossible. If I were you, I'd put together a demo of the closest thing you can come up with and show us the code so I can accept your answer.